# Is "for" attribute necessary in HTML label if the target input is nested inside the label?

Tags: html, input, label

I've noticed that a HTML label tag doesn't need the 'for' attribute when you put your input element into the label element:

```
<label><input type="text">Last name</label>
```

But I was wondering what's the best practise. Can anybody help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: Like WebMonster stated, it's fine to do it your way.  Just keep your use consistent throughout your code.

Comment: I noticed today that [Bootstrap's documentation uses both in the same form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline). It seems that the `for` attribute is intended *only if* you can't or don't put the `<input>` inside the `<label>` itself, and either approach is acceptable.

Comment: I also have this question.  So many online "answers" pretend the question is whether to associate labels with particular elements _at all_, as though the person asking didn't care about accessibility.  **That is not the question.**  The question is whether to use `for` when it is technically redundant because the label directly contains the labeled element; and if so, why?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's used for accessibility for screen readers and the like i.e.

[use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

So you should use it. And here is a [link](http://www.webnauts.net/accessibility.html) to convince you about the importance of accessibily.

And here is a little story - making your site accessible can benefit all users - i always was amazed at the amount of effort civic authorities went to for wheelchair accessibilty until I had a daughter and use a push chair. I think websites follow the same rule - everyone benefits.

Apologies for the polemic

Comment: Eh, too much work. Get your site running first, then if you have free time to spare, add in all the accessibility stuff.

Comment: Although your site isn't really "running" if many users can't use it (due to broken accessibility).

Answer (score 23):

Both the [W3 HTML 5.2 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-label-for) and the [WhatWG Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-label-for) state (in almost exact terms, quote is from the latter):

> The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the same tree as the label element. If the attribute is specified and there is an element in the tree whose ID is equal to the value of the for attribute, and the first such element in tree order is a labelable element, then that element is the label element's labeled control.

So it's okay to use it that way in terms of following the HTML standard.

Answer (score 8):

The for attribute doesn't make much difference with a text input, but is very useful with a checkbox input, as it allows users to click on the label as well as the checkbox itself:

```
<label for="chk">Checkbox</label><input type="checkbox" id="chk" />
```

Comment: An input tag can be inside a label. See https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/forms.html#writing-a-form-s-user-interface

Comment: Thanks @SarathSMenon - I've removed that bit

Answer (score 5):

You can include the `input` in your `label` and it is associated with the `label`, or if for some reason you have to have your `label` element elsewhere in the DOM, you can specify it's meaning with the `for` attribute. It never hurts to use the `for`attribute though either way :)