# Keep Bootstrap Dropdown Open When Clicked Inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu. I want it to be *kept open when I click inside it*, but closed when clicking the dropdown toggle button or outside of the menu.

It seems like the dropdown does not close when I type something in the `input` but it closes when I click anywhere else inside the dropdown.

**Q:** How can I avoid this by using jQuery?

Below is my **HTML**:

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU</a> 
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <input>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

#### [Demo in Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/dlVkCbKony)

Comment: The answer should be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/twitter-bootstrap-avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside

Comment: @NathanGalea I tried this but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following JavaScript to manually open and close the dropdown menu:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(window).on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp();
  });

});
```

#### Demo in StackSnippets

```js
$(function() {

  $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(window).on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <p>Hello</p>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a problem with this one. When I click on other links and try to click menu again, the sub dropdown does not show anymore. How do I fix it?

Comment: @H.Kim Can you please post your code by editing your question again. So that I can guess what is going to be wrong..?

Comment: so for example, when I click on other link and I am directed to another page, I can no longer open the `menu` I'm using ruby on rails at the moment

Comment: Are you using this script on all pages on which you want to achieve this effect..?

Comment: I think so. I put the javascript code into `application.js` file and it should affect all pages. my other links look like this: `<li ><%=link_to( image_tag("menu2.png"), root_url) %></li>` and when I click on links like this, it won't work. but if I refresh the page, it works.

Comment: Becuase I have no idea about ruby on rails so I would suggest you to use this code on all pages.....! It will works properly..!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147342/discussion-between-rohit-sharma-and-h-kim).

Answer (score 5):

From the question [Avoid dropdown menu close on click inside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32922725/1366033),  you can simply stop propagation from inside the [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns) like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus .dropdown-menu', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

#### Demo in Stack Snipets

```js
$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus .dropdown-menu', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown allow-focus">
  <button id="dropdownLabel" type="button" class="btn btn-default"
          data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu panel" aria-labelledby="dropdownLabel">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      What's Your Name?
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **NOTE**: To solve the *opposite* problem (of keeping open *until* clicked), you can refer to:
>
> [Keep Bootstrap Dropdown Open When Clicked **Off**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19797577/1366033)