# html5 div inside label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to ensure my webapp is HTML5 compliant and by doing so I discovered an HTML5 error. I am currently using the following code:

```
<label><div class="someClass"><input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" value="0">Some text goes here</div></label>
<label><div class="someClass"><input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" value="1">Some text goes here</div></label>
<label><div class="someClass"><input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" value="2">Some text goes here</div></label>
```

My intention is to create a container using a div and css for styling, so when the user clicks anywhere on the container, the corresponding box is automatically checked. Is there a better method of doing this without a great deal of javascript or jquery? Please keep in mind the number of check boxes will vary.

Comment: Why can't you just style the label?

Comment: This is what the `for` attribute is for. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432376/what-does-for-attribute-do-in-html-label-tag

Comment: Fast solution: switch `<div>` to `<span>` and set it to be `display: block`.

Comment: Squint, at the time of creating the objects I did try formatting the label, but I was not getting the formatting I wanted. After doing more research, I found there are block elements and non-block elements, and you can change a block to a non-block item and non-block to a block item.

This comes from inexperience and self teaching.

Comment: SatJ, at the time of creating the objects I just found the above method and was not aware this coding was out of compliance. When I was reviewing the code and checking for HTML5 issues, I just couldn't see the forest through the trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display:block` for the label

```css
label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" value="0">Some text goes here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" value="1">Some text goes here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" value="2">Some text goes here</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `for` attribute on the `<label>` elements to tell what checkbox the label is for. That way when a user clicks on the label, the checkbox will toggle:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" id="first" value="0"><label for="first" class="someClass">Some text goes here</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" id="second" value="0"><label for="second" class="someClass">Some text goes here</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" id="third" value="0"><label for="third" class="someClass">Some text goes here</label>
```

Answer (score -2):

Joining @satJ answer with @zzzzBov comment, I would do:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" id="first" value="0"><label for="first"><span class="someClass">Some text goes here</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" id="second" value="0"><label for="second"><span class="someClass">Some text goes here</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="ChkBox[]" id="third" value="0"><label for="third"><span class="someClass">Some text goes here</span></label>
```