# jquery - removing the "hide" class on DIV is not showing the label inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which is hidden in a form (class="hide"), when I click a button then that div be shown by removing the class "hide".
That div is having a label and a button . The label is not shown when the "hide" class is removed dynamically.
But the buttons are shown. Only the label is missing. Let me know the problem here.

```
<div id="UpdateDiv" class="hide" class="col-lg-12">
  <div align="right" style="margin:10px;">
    <label id='UpdateSuccess'>Update Successful</label>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-left:10px; width:100px;">
      <i class="demo-icon icon-cw-1 fa-fw" style="font-size:1.3em;"> </i> Update
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:120px; border:0px ">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>


$("#UpdateDiv").removeClass("hide");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not a solution, but your `<label>` tag isn't pointing to anything. please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432376/what-does-for-attribute-do-in-html-label-tag

Comment: What does `" ')">` and `"` in `">` stand for?

Answer (score 2):

I think you messed up your quotes:

```
<div id="UpdateDiv" class="hide" class="col-lg-12">
    <div align="right" style="margin:10px;">
        <label id="UpdateSuccess">Update Successful</label>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-left:10px; width:100px;">
            <i class="demo-icon icon-cw-1 fa-fw" style="font-size:1.3em;"> </i> Update
        </a>
        <button type="button" id="Cancel_{{hubName}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:120px; border:0px"> Cancel</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Although `' ">` is wrong in the original code, attributes in HTML5 do not necessarily need quotes (only if you use a space like in classnames than quotation is necessary)

Comment: Yes I know. I added them since this looks like a beginner code to me, so I want to get him used to it in order to not have the space problem in the future.

Comment: Yes, best. Mine was more like a follow-up to your answer

Comment: Oh ok, you are right though, thanks for pointing that out. Now he'll be double aware of it in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your html is wrong. I have fixed this here.

```js
$("#UpdateDiv").removeClass("hide");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=UpdateDiv class="hide" class="col-lg-12">
  <div align="right" style="margin:10px;">
    <label id='UpdateSuccess'>Update Successful</label>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-left:10px; width:100px;">
      <i class="demo-icon icon-cw-1 fa-fw" style="font-size:1.3em;"> </i> Update
    </a>
    <button type="button" id=Cancel_{{hubName}} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:120px; border:0px ">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (P.S: Rajan, if there's nothing to *run* remove the `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->`)