# What is the use of "for" atribute of HTML5?

Tags: html

I'm currently learning HTML and I am having difficulties understanding the `for` attribute of `<label>`.

Can anyone clarify this to me with examples?

Comment: Just as side comment... it's not `HTML5` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Its used for inputs, it binds `<input for="myId">` to `<span id="myId">`

Also see:
[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432439/6799340) and the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)