# control label getting highlighted when triggering validationin angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am implementing validation in my angular 4 validation and need to do some tweaks. The validation works fine but probably need to alter the way the message is displayed. At the moment when i click the save button on the form the control a message is displayed below the control and control borders get highlighted in red as well the control label. I dont want to the control label to be highlighted in red. One way i can think of is using the regular label tag but cant i achieve the same using label for. Is (label for) recommended ? what are the benefits. ? How do I use (label for) and yet not highlight the label

```html
<form [formGroup]="newMovieForm" (ngSubmit)="save(newMovieForm.value, newMovieForm.valid)">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!newMovieForm.controls['title'].valid && (saveClicked || newMovieForm.controls['title'].touched)}">
        <label for="movie-title" class="control-label">Title of Movie</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movie-title" placeholder="Title of Movie" formControlName="title" maxlength="100">
        <!-- The hasError method will tell us if a particular error exists -->
        <div *ngIf="newMovieForm.controls['title'].hasError('required') && (saveClicked || newMovieForm.controls['title'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">Title is required.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with using the `for` attribute. The reason your label is highlighted in red is because it has the [`control-label`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L2874) class applied:

```
.has-error .control-label {
    color: #a94442;
}
```

You can just remove that class from your label to get the result you want. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css), this class only affects label colours, unless used in horizontal, inline or navbar forms.

If you still want to use `control-label`, you could always override the CSS to reset the colour, but this will be unnecessary in your exact example.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432439/2630078) answer explains the use of the `for` attribute specifically, but as I've said, that's not impacting the highlighting of your label here.