# Click on div row select input

Tags: css

I am trying to accomplish wherever in div I make a click it will mark input radio as selected item. In my situation it works only if I click on radio, on other places in same row it does not work

```
 <div class="row" style="padding-top:30px; cursor:pointer;"> 
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-1"> 
        <div class="box"  style="margin-top:-15px"> 
            <input type="radio" name="order" class="form-radio" value="1" onclick="selectValue()" id="checkbox" />                                
        </div>                            
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-5">
        <div class="box">
           Mercedes CLS250
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-5">
        <div class="box pull-right">
            <p style="text-align:right;">2000KB</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row" style="padding-top:30px; cursor:pointer;"> 
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-1"> 
            <div class="box"  style="margin-top:-15px"> 
                <input type="radio" name="order" class="form-radio" value="2" onclick="selectValue()" id="checkbox" />                                
            </div>                            
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-5">
            <div class="box">
               Mercedes CLS350
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-5">
            <div class="box pull-right">
                <p style="text-align:right;">300KB</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have used css cursor pointer but when I make a click it does not select chosen row.

Comment: Could you transform your example into a runnable [mcve]? What you posted doesn't work in a browser and it's not clear what you're asking. To make it runnable use the `<>` button from edit mode and place HTML, CSS and JS in each panel. Also add any external resources, making sure it reproduces the same behavior as in your project.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a text block which when is clicked on, it triggers a click for the input radio button.

To do that, all you need is a `label` with the attribute of `for="input_id_goes_here"`. Here's an example:

```
<label for="female">Female</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
```

With that code, anytime you click the `label`, then the `input` will get selected. If you want to know more about the `for` attribute, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432376/what-does-for-attribute-do-in-html-label-tag).

FYI, the `onclick` attribute is for `JavaScript`.

Let me know if this helps and if you have anymore questions.

**Update**

Another way to change a radio input when a block of text is selected, is to wrap your input with a label, like this:

```
<label>Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"></label>
```

So for your code, all you have to do is change `<div class="row"> to <label class="row">`.

Thanks to @KoshVery for pointing it out in the comments below!

Comment: if `input` is wrapped into `label`  attributes `id` and `for` are not needed:
`<label>Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"></label>`. So all they need is change `<div class="row">` to `<label class="row">`.

Comment: @KoshVery, except it breaks the layout if you don't specify the `display` attribute. That's why you should **never** answer a question or provide a suggestion to improve one without actually testing.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, if you'd like nitpicking, there is no `display` attribute, `display` is a CSS property. The main idea was using `label` as a wrapper and I wrote my own answer, but saw that @SteveCahn had answered already. So I commented to improve their answer instead of posting mine. Your answer appeared 11 minutes later and as it's seen from its editions history it had a beautiful evolution. You've included @Paulus' answer either. So I'd like to notice that you should **never** copy other people's solutions to your answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Kosh, I wrote a new answer because none of the existing ones were meeting what I hold as SO quality standard. Adding a [mcve] to an answer is where I draw the line between suggesting an improvement and my own answer. I suggest you revise your voting reasoning: who answers first is irrelevant on [SO]. It's all about the answer's quality. Whether it matters to you or not, or you believe it or not, I have noticed the duplicated ids in the snippet itself, not in Paulus's answer (for some reason I didn't read it until you pointed to it - most likely because of its poor formatting).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, I really appreciate your efforts, but SO quality standard you're holding has nothing in common with the very first edition of your answer. It's a known SO tactics: answer "meow" then replace it with a real solution and get score. But I believe it's more important for SO to help new contributors to post good answers and reward their attempts.

Comment: @Kosh, when you say you appreciate my efforts you sound dishonest. The first edition of my answer was superior, as a SO answer, to the current edition of Steve's answer. It contained a working [mcve] and worked. You *"appreciated"* mine by down-voting while up-voting his. I agree with rewarding new contributor's efforts. But he ignored my initial suggestion to link the official spec. Which is why I never suggested another improvement. I added a better answer. What exactly should I reward? And what does "answer meow" mean?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, I like your final(?) answer, but I do not like how it appeared. That's it. Also I do not like your habit to judge and tell people their shoulds and should-nots, especially regarding commenting and voting.

Answer (score 0):

you have id = "checkbox" in both inputs. ids need to be unique

```
 <input type="radio" name="order" class="form-radio" value="2" 
 onclick="selectValue()" id="checkbox" />
```

if you want to fire the whole div when clicked, add the function to the whole row div