# Custom Checkbox Rails / CSS

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to be able to click on the label to check my element without showing the checked so I wrote this:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]
{
   display: none;
 }
```

But when I click it doesn't work. It only works if the element is already in the database.

Do I have to do javascript or can CSS do it?

```rb
#views/values/edit.html.erb*

<% @values =["Power", "Independance", "Tradition"] %>
<%= form_for @resultvalue do |f| %>
   <% @values.each do | value | %>
       <%= f.check_box :values, { multiple: true }, value, type:"checkbox" %>
       <%= f.label value %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit%>  
<% end %>
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
        display: none;
      }
      input[type="checkbox"]+label{
        transition: all 300ms ease;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        border: 3px solid white;
        background-color: #0066cc;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;

        // Suggested by @zizzo to prevent text selection
        -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        // ------------------------


      }
      input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label{
        transition: all 300ms ease;
        background-color:#b70e7e;  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `for` attribute to your labels with the `id` of the associated checkbox. That way, clicking the label will let you interact with the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
<label for="checkbox1">Label name</label>
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432439](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432439/9540991)

Answer (score 0):

There's no attribute "multiple" on input tags, also you don't need to set `type: 'checkbox'` since you are already using the checkbox helper, and you are passing `:values` which I don't think makes sense.

For the label to properly change the checkbox state, you need to set the `for` attribute properly with the ID of the corresponding checkbox https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/label

You can also nest the input tag INSIDE the label so you don't need the `for` attribute.

Finally, `collection_check_boxes` would be cleaner than your code https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes

Comment: I don't know how to use collection_check_boxes in my situation, with an array like this @arieljuod

Comment: It's a little tricky/hacky but I guess something like `= f.collection_check_boxes :values, @values, :to_s, :to_s` should work. It applies both methods (`to_s`) to each element of the collection to get the value and the label, calling `to_s` just returns the same string for both.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with Rails, but what I would do is either assign an id to the checkbox and use a for attribute on the label

```html
<label for="my_input">My input</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_input"/>
```

or I would wrap the input in the label

```
<%= f.label value %>
  <%= f.check_box :values, { multiple: true }, value, type:"checkbox" %>
<% end %>
```