# Using for and name attribute together

Tags: html

Earlier I studied that for `text` type input tag  `id` attribute and `for` attribute of the `label` tag should have the same value.

Now I was reading a [tutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-change-event/) and came through this code, here in the case of `radio buttons` the `for` and `name` attribute have the same value, instead of `id` and `for`.

And I am aware that `id` is unique for an element. My first question is then what is the purpose of using the `for` attribute in the case of radio buttons?

```
<label for="status">Status:</label>
<input type="radio" id="pending" name="status"> Pending
<input type="radio" id="resolved" name="status"> Resolved
<input type="radio" id="rejected" name="status"> Rejected
```

My second question is that unlike the `text` type input tag here `id` and `for` attribute do not have the same value. Is it a valid code? If it is valid then what is the purpose of giving the same values to the `for` and `name` attribute?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "for" attribute do in HTML <label> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432376/what-does-for-attribute-do-in-html-label-tag)

Comment: Label is to select a field. If you're assigning label to radio, each radio must have it's own label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I was reading a tutorial and came through this code, here in the case of radio buttons the for and name attribute have the same value, instead of id and for.

This is an error

> And I am aware that id is unique for an element. My first question is then what is the purpose of using the for attribute in the case of radio buttons?

The `for` attribute should have the same value as the `id` of the radio button it is labelling

> My second question is that unlike the text type input tag here id and for attribute do not have the same value. Is it a valid code? If it is valid then what is the purpose of giving the same values to the for and name attribute?

Entirely valid.

The name determines that the key will be when the form data is submitted and groups the radio buttons.

The id is used to uniquely identify it (e.g. for a label).

> ```
> <label for="status">Status:</label>
> <input type="radio" id="pending" name="status"> Pending
> <input type="radio" id="resolved" name="status"> Resolved
> <input type="radio" id="rejected" name="status"> Rejected
> ```

The words to the right of the inputs should be labels here.

The label should be a legend for a fieldset.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Status</legend>
  <input type="radio" id="pending" name="status"> <label for="pending">Pending</label>
  <input type="radio" id="resolved" name="status"> <label for="resolved">Resolved</label>
  <input type="radio" id="rejected" name="status"> <label for="rejected">Rejected</label>
</fieldset>
```

Note how, in the live demo, you can click the label to trigger the associated radio button. (Aside from the larger click target and conformance to standard UI conventions, this also benefits screen reader & other AT software).

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct use of a `label`.

The `label` should be associated with a single control, so in your case you would need a `label` for each `input`. And if you want to group them, you can add a `fieldset` element with a `legend` to "label" it.

something like

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Status:</legend>
  <input type="radio" id="pending" name="status"> <label for="pending">Pending</label>
  <input type="radio" id="resolved" name="status"> <label for="resolved">Resolved</label>
  <input type="radio" id="rejected" name="status"> <label for="rejected">Rejected</label>
</fieldset>
```

(*and you can of-course style it the way you want it to look*)